# Не могу выровнять текст в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Уже 3 часа убил да что же это такое!
как выравнять этот долбаный эдит текст???
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="312.25dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#ffff281b"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etEmailSkip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#ff1515ff"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical"/>

            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgGo"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fbSignUp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fbSignUp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

мне нужно чтобы сам текст в самом едиттексте был поцентру по вертикали. как это сделать?

Comment: а Вы пробовали использовать CENTER, CENTER_HORIZONTAL, CENTER_VERTICAL из http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/Gravity.html и примеры http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-s-gravity-layout-gravity-padding-and-layout-margin-attributes.html

Comment: конечно пробовал)))я не совсем новичок в андроид. все перепробовал

Answer (score 4):

Доброго времени суток!

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etEmailSkip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#ff1515ff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

- `android:layout_gravity="...."` - отвечает за положение данного слоя, к которому Вы указываете параметр выравнивания
- `android:gravity="...."` - отвечает за положение элементов **в текущем слое**

Немного о параметрах выравнивания по центру:

- `center_vertical` - выравнять по вертикали
- `center_horizontal` - выровнять по горизонтали
- `center` - выровнять по вертикали и по горизонтали